# Simulate SYSDATE Oracle function in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have been trying to simulate the following Oracle statement in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

To reach this, I was already able to simulate the TRUNC() function receiving only one time datatype parameter, which is `timestamp without time zone`. This is how I made it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.trunc(teste TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE)
RETURNS TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN
  RETURN DATE_TRUNC('DAY', teste);
END
$BODY$
language 'plpgsql';
```

It works just fine when I try to call this function passing the CLOCK_TIMESTAMP() function as an argument but casting it at the same time. Just like this:

```
SELECT TRUNC(CLOCK_TIMESTAMP()::TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE);
```

So that I can get around this whole statement, I'd like to make it more practical replacing this entire argument for SYSDATE. I've already tried to create the same SYSDATE function in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sysdate()
RETURNS TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE
AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  RETURN DATE_TRUNC('SECOND', CLOCK_TIMESTAMP() AT TIME ZONE '<<My_timezone>>');
END
$BODY$
language plpgsql;
```

Well... I'm not gonna say it does not work, because it does. Nevertheless, everytime I call the TRUNC() function created by me, I need to pass SYSDATE as an argument using parentheses:

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE());
```

That is, although it is similar from what I am trying to simulate, it isn't syntactically correct. Would there be a way to take off the parentheses from it while calling SYSDATE function?

Futhermore, is there any observation to be done about what I am trying to do? It's important to quote that the `timestamp without time zone` was chosen by purpose, although SYSDATE returns DATE type by default.

Comment: Can't you use `select current_date;` ? See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9d8b79d0760ed77c3920853bd8e2cb7e

Comment: @TheImpaler, I can't because the datetype chosen to be used was the ```timestamp without time zone``` by default. That's why those functions and casting were made as being of this type, moreover, the central idea is to use the keyword ```SYSDATE```.

Comment: If you are looking for something that works in Oracle and Postgres, then using `current_date` would achieve that.

Comment: No need for plpgsql, a simple SQL function can do the trick

Comment: @FrankHeikens: but that still doesn't allow to create  a function where you can leave out the parentheses

Answer (score 1):

You cannot to create function in Postgres, that can be called without parenthesis. This is not supported. Every call of function have to use parenthesis.